# How to find {n^3}{1000} - 100n^2 - 100n + 3 in terms of Θ and prove it?

Tags: algorithm

I am reading Introduction to Algorithms by coreman and came across this below exercise:

```
Express the function {n^3}{1000} - 100n^2 - 100n + 3 in terms of the Θ notation
```

I do not have any computer science background, so trying to learn algorithms using this book. Looking at the above equation I thought the answer is O(n^3).

But when I saw this post - [How to find n^3/1000−100n2−100n+3 in terms of Θ and prove it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507283/how-to-find-fracn31000-100n2-100n-3-in-terms-of-%CE%98-and-prove-it)

The question in the above post has some explanation using f(n) and g(n) with constants C1 and C2 etc which I am not able to understand how the OP tried to solve it using some equations.

Also, the answer given by Ross, he mentioned it as `Now you have a positive bound on  C1`. What this indicates. Please help me in understanding the concepts here.

Comment: `f(n) = O(g(n))` means that you can find some **positive finite** constant `C1` which satisfies the inequality `|f(n)| <= C1 * |g(n)|` for *all positive* values of `n`.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, I did not understand the question posed by OP itself, what are those functions f(n) and g(n) and what are those constants C1 and C2, what he is trying to achieve with those to justify result as O(n^3)

Comment: In this example `f(n) = n^3/1000 - 100n^2 - 100n + 3` and `g(n) = n^3`. He shows that `f(n) = O(g(n))` by finding a value of `C1` which satisfies `|f(n)| <= C1 * |g(n)|` for all large values of `n` (in this case `C1 = 1` works).

Comment: The topic you are interested in is called Landau notations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations  You should consider reading more about this before asking questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The answer's going to be Θ(n3).

To work it out systematically, the easiest thing to do is to use the Seven Rules for Big-O and Θ at [http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~guttman/cs2223/seven_rules.pdf](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Eguttman/cs2223/seven_rules.pdf).
Writing e for the original expression, rule (2) applied repeatedly tells us
Θ(e) = Θ(max(n^3/1000 - 100n^2 - 100n + 3))

Applying rule (1) to each of these, this will equal Θ(max(n^3, n^2, n, 1)).

Now we can apply rule (4) to see that Θ(1) < Θ(n) < Θ(n^2) < Θ(n^3):

So Θ(max(n^3, n^2, n, 1)) = Θ(n^3).

Comment: The question is "How to find {n^3}{1000} - 100n^2 - 100n + 3 in terms of Θ and prove it?" How does your answer answer this?